# How can I get all users who have access to office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I don't know if it's even possible but can we all users who have access to office 365 using code ?

Ideally I need them in a SharePoint hosted app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Graph API to get list of tenant users as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations).

In a nutshell, you call Graph API via REST using `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version=1.6`.

More details how to configure access to app and authorization & authorization [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview).

Comment: yet to test it but accept it for now, thank you very much